# Inserting Multiple Rows with one Stored Producer

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions, mysql-insert-id

Good Day.

I'm working on the Stored Producer of MySql.
is it possible to insert multiple rows in a single Stored Producer, **spinsertmultiple(pname, pdateTimeFrom, pdateTimeTo)**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`PROCEDURE `spinsertmultiple`
( pname varchar(32), pdateTimeFrom DATETIME, pdateTimeTo DATETIME)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO vesseleventsactual(
    name, time, date
    )
    VALUES(
    pname, ??, ??
    );
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I don't have the right codes what should I write in my values. to add multiple rows.

Example:

> CALL spinsertmultiple('name', '2015-08-17 8:00:00', '2015-08-17 12:00:00');

Expected Output in my table (Columns in my table: *name* | *time* | *date*)

```
name | 8:00:00 | 2015-08-17
name | 9:00:00 | 2015-08-17
name | 10:00:00 | 2015-08-17
name | 11:00:00 | 2015-08-17
name | 12:00:00 | 2015-08-17
```

I've been doing some research but all solutions are using **INSERT INTO tablename (colname ...) VALUES (values ...), (values ...), (values ...)**

Comment: Stored procedure is the term and you would need to post that too.

Comment: Done @e4c5 adding my stored producer code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one possible solution would be using a loop. You subtract the difference of your start and end times, and use that for your counter.

Semi pseudo-code / SQL:

```
SET @inserts = 1
SET @insertsNeeded = @EndTime.Hours - @StartTime.Hours

WHILE(@inserts <= @insertsNeeded)
    INSERT INTO tablename(...)
    @inserts = @inserts + 1
```

Comment: @insert, What's the first value of this?

Comment: @MeSoftware: that starts at 1 and you increment it for every iteration through your loop.

Comment: insertsNeeded = insertsNeeded + 1
So this should be insert = insert + 1,?

Comment: @MeSoftware yes, my mistake.

Comment: Can you teach me about how to use ADDTIME()? 
**ADDTIME(ptimefrom, '1:00:00');** I tried doing it like that. but I have an error *1064* **(ptimefrom, '1:00:00');**

Comment: my ptimefrom is DATETIME